# populate active admin form when data is not validate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have activeadmin form

```
> f.input :title, label: 'Title', :input_html =>{ :required => ''}   li
> do
>     f.label :location
>     f.select :location, options_for_select([['Community', 'Community'], ['Learn More', 'Learn More']]), :prompt => "Select
> Location" ,:collection => displayable_collection   end   li do
>     f.label :Type
>     f.select :content_type, options_for_select([['Article', 'Article'], ['Gallery', 'Gallery'], ['Video', 'Video']]), :prompt =>
> "Select Type", :id => 'content_type'   end
```

when form is submit and error come , form filed content no value, I want to populate form if error comes.

Answer (score 0):

try with,

```
   f.input :title, label: 'Title', :input_html =>{ :required => '', :value => f.object.title} 
   do
     f.label :location
     f.select :location, options_for_select([['Community', 'Community'], ['Learn More', 'Learn More']], :selected => f.object.location), :prompt => "Select  Location" ,:collection => displayable_collection   end   li do
     f.label :Type
     f.select :content_type, options_for_select([['Article', 'Article'], ['Gallery', 'Gallery'], ['Video', 'Video']], :selected => f.object.content_type), :prompt =>  "Select Type", :id => 'content_type'
   end
```

Its not, what instance value f object is holding. That's why i have written `f.object`. You can directly use instacen like, `@user.location`

Comment: I am using activeadmin form have no method in controller